# c# call KeyDown event from a DoubleClick event

Tags: c#

I have some code written in my KeyDown event that I want to execute from a Double Click event. I could wrap that code block as a function and call that function in both events, but I just want to use a fancy way to avoid creating a new function. This is what my two events look like.

```
private void txtProduct_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)  
{  
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)  
    {
        //do something  
    }  
}  

private void listProduct_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtProduct_KeyDown(txtProduct, Keys.Return);
}
```

In order to execute the `//do something` block from doubleclick event, I need to call keydown event with two specific arguments. what is it? any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass `KeyEventArgs` you need this

```
txtProduct_KeyDown(txtProduct, new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Enter));
```

Although it's not the best way to do it as coding practices are concerned, you should create a function which performs that **dosomething** for you and then call it from anywhere in the world.

Comment: Thanks but yes i know that. i just dont know how do i make a keyEventArgs object that has the keyCode of Return key, and then pass it to the KeyDown event. an example might help.

Answer (score 3):

Don't go there.  **Always** extract common functionality into its own method. Trying fancy stuff to avoid creating a new method will only cause you pain in the long run.

```
private void txtProduct_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)  
{  
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)  
    {
        DoSomething(); 
    }  
}  

private void listProduct_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}  

private void DoSomething()
{
    // Do Something
}
```

That is painless and expresses exactly what you want to do, namely `DoSomething` both on list doubleclick and Return Keydown.

Answer (score 0):

Following code passes Enter Key Press event to a particular method.

```
txtProduct_KeyDown(new object(), new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.Enter));
```